# Boot issue ubuntu 18.04 Dell precision tower 5810: no access to grub, stuck on screen with green/blueish stripes at the top

Tags: 18.04, boot-partition

I have been using ubuntu for over a year but am quite novice in the world of customizable booting disks/partitionning/BIOS utility and so on.

I have issues booting my ubuntu installation that I have been using for a while without any problem, it only started occurring recently. When I turn my computer on, I see the boot screen (Dell logo in my case) from where I am eventually able to access the BIOS utility and play around with the booting parameters. Then, various loading screens follow each other, ending with the one with “press Ctrl+I to enter configuration utility”. Afterwards, when I would usually be able to enter GRUB and select *Ubuntu, my screen turns black with many short green and blue stripes sitting on the top (in the pattern 2 green, one blue/green, 2 green, one blue/green...). And nothing else happens from there - the only way to exit it is to force shut down the computer manually. Eventually, every 20 times, it works though: I can access ubuntu. Then I ran boot-repair several times already, and it did not solve my problem.

My installation is:
- Dell precision tower 5810
- Ubuntu 18.04, on the 2nd partition of a disk containing a windows 7 installation. The ubuntu partition is several hundreds of Go away from the beginning of the disk, boot-repair pointed out that this could be an issue, but I do bot succeed to make the ubuntu partition jump to the left of my windows partition (you can only populate free space adjacent to your partition, you cannot “jump” another partition if you see what I mean) so I did not succeed to put it close to the beginning of the disk.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update: the issue seemed unresolvable, including by the IT of my lab - the only solution was to completely replace the motherboard, sadly.

On the same page: if anyone gets stuck with a black/weird screen at boot, a turnaround can be to UNPLUG ALL THE HARD DISKS (except from the booting disk obviously) from the machine before booting it - your computer may try to boot on drives with no OS on it (even if NOT on the list of bootable drives on BIOS, quite oddly) and get stuck there, for some reason. This also happened to me.